# Maven compiler plugin error: can't access enum (bad signature, bad class)

Tags: java, maven, enums, javac

I am using `maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2` and every time I make changes in classes which have an enum (`ContentType`) in imports, I need to make `clean`, otherwise it gives me:

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project wp2: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/semyon/development/.../ContentManager.java:[15,46] error: cannot access ContentType
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project wp2: Compilation failure
/home/semyon/development/.../ContentManager.java:[15,46] error: cannot access ContentType

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:364)
...
```

ContentType is `enum` and looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public enum ContentType {

    ...; 

    private final String title;

    private final boolean hasJad;

    private final CoreType coreType;

    private final String[] searchKeywords;



    ContentType(@NotNull String title, CoreType coreType, boolean hasJad, String[] searchKeywords) {
        this.title = title;
        this.coreType = coreType;

        this.hasJad = hasJad;
        this.searchKeywords = searchKeywords;
    }

    @NotNull
    public String getTitle() {
         return title;
    }

    @NotNull
    public String getName() {
        return name();
    }

    @NotNull
    public CoreType getCoreType() {
        return coreType;
    }

    public enum CoreType {

         ...;

        private String title;

        CoreType(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

    }
}
```

UPD1, project structure:

```
        /wp2
             /core
                  /cpe
                     /widget
                           /ContentManager.java
                  /cdr
                     /entities
                           /ContentType.java
```

UPD 2:

ContentManager.java:[15,46] is `import wp2.core.cdr.entities.ContentType;`

UPD 3: 
Modern compiler will show `bad class` and `bad signature` errors as well

Comment: Post your `pom.xml` and show us your directory structure.

Comment: @carlspring pom is WAY too large to post it (~4000 lines), so maybe you can tell me what is important?

Comment: just post it on pastebin or on gist

Comment: i'm interested in ContentManager.java:[15,46] that file as well

Comment: got u, sometimes i have same kind of problems as well

Comment: @Mysterion just to make it clear: it's the only enum that shows such errors, also it fails on any class, that imports it, so I need to recompile entire project. If I remove compiled ContentType.class from `target`, it compiles just fine. But the error seems so strange, so I want to know if there is any logical explanation

Comment: @SemyonDanilov: As Mysterion said, seeing the `ContentManager` class would also help. Are you sure your package names are right? In your comment you say it's `ru.sofitlabs.wp2.core.cdr.entities.ContentType`, whereas in your code it's just `wp2.core.cdr.entities.ContentType`...?

Comment: @carlspring there was an edit made by Mysterion and he remove `ru.sofitlabs` (i think because it's not necessary). About `ContentManager` - it won't make any sense, because any class importing `ContentType` fails to compile

Comment: yeah, i remove it, sorry for inconvinience, but it's better not to share your company name :) at least it's my humble opinion

Comment: @Mysterion would the `plugins` part be enough? I don't think, that dependencies are involved in it, as both `ContentType` and `ContentManager` are in the project

Comment: @Mysterion https://gist.github.com/SammyVimes/3681a581ebc3bfee311e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69612/discussion-between-mysterion-and-semyon-danilov).

Comment: @Mysterion I was able to finally find out the answer, I posted it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found an answer

The error is in the costructor:

`ContentType(@NotNull String title...`

Constructors in enum must not have annotations in it, as `javac` is bugged.
Javac stores incorrect signature for `enum` constructor (the one you writes, and not the one actually is used - it has two additional params as I recall). 
When `javac` verifies the signature it sees **annotated** parameter and in my case that was the **first** parameter. BUT in the **actual** signature (`String name, int ordinal, String title, CoreType coreType, boolean hasJad, String[] searchKeywords`, two first params are added by enum -> Enum translation) `title` is only **third** parameter and **first** parameter is `name` which is **not annotated** and javac thinks that class is incorrect.

**tl;dr** remove annotation from constructor, javac is buggy

Comment: Which version of Java is that? Does it still happen with Java 8? Note: You can compile code for a Java 6 VM / runtime with Java 8.

Comment: I compiled with both 6 and 7 java, didn't try with 8 (I suppose the problem persists as [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8024694) remains unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bug in the code which tries to determine which classes need to be compiled after a change.

Try the latest version of the [Maven compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/). The version number is on the page behind the link, in the header on the right, below the Maven logo (`3.2` at the time of writing).

Comment: With version 3.2 it simply recompiles all classes even if only one class was changed.

Comment: That might be a new bug but it solves your issue. As far as I remember, the "recompile the minimum set of files after a change" is still an experimental feature.

Comment: That explains everything. I will try building and running maven in debug mode to see what exactly happens in MojoExecutor and why it can't access the class.

Comment: The exception is thrown from `javac`, so I don't think I can do much there:(

Comment: The question is why doesn't the Maven compiler plugin notice it has to recompile the enum as well. But I don't know how to debug the code which determines which files changed and what depends on those files.

Comment: Actually I found a solution and I will post it in a hour. Also, about incremental compilation: it has to be set to false in configuration because of a bug in compiler-plugin.